# NGINX doesn't resolve when website is accessing through Mozila Firefox browser

Tags: nginx, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress, nginx-config, mozilla

[image]Hi all! We have an issue with DNS resolving when our website accessing from Mozila browser, all other browsers works fine tho. We use kubernetes nginx deployment with custom `nginx.conf` file which contains all our upstreams(locations to our applications running on kubernetes) which attached to the nginx ingress. When I try to access website from Chrome or any browsers it works fine, but when I use Mozila, the DNS name is changing on my kubernetes service where we store our static assets and not resolving, for example:
[www.example.com](http://www.example.com) => http://static-assets.default.svc.cluster.local/
Appreciate for the help!

So basically I expect that site should be reached from any browser